# CSS issue with border colors

Tags: css

Using the code below I'm expecting a green rectangle and a red one of the same size. But instead, the red is half the size of the green

Any suggestion how to make it the same size?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css"> 
      #menu ul{list-style:none;}   
      #menu ul li{float:left;width:103px;height:43px;border:5px solid green;}
      #menu ul li #menu1 {border:solid 2px red;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><div id="menu1"><a href="#">1 </a></div></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, you don't understand why a `div` of unspecified height is not the same size as a `li` of height 43px?

Comment: First you have to learn the basics of HTML & CSS. Then ask question.

Comment: @sandeep OR you could try to explain the basics of CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the css I used.

`#menu ul{list-style:none;}

   #menu ul li{float:left; width:103px; height:43px; 
border:5px solid green; position:relative; padding:0 0 3px 0 ;}
   #menu ul li #menu1 { border:solid 2px red; height:100%; }​`

Notice the first thing is the addition of the `height:100%;` but also because of the border. I also added a padding of half the size to the bottom of the wrapper. If you remove that you will see better.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z5vJS/)

Comment: Thank you very much kwelch! Thanks to you my problem is solved and in addition I know what is it i do not understand in CSS: inheritence. I thought: #menu ul li #menu1 would inherit its' sizes from #menu ul li.

Answer (score 0):

Set a height for `#menu1`

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8V9K5/1/)

Comment: Had i not assigned height to the whole bunch of them list items?!

Answer (score 0):

you get different heights because the `li` has fixed height of 43px and the `#menu1` hasn't. If you wish to fill the gap add `height:39px` for `#menu1`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/EyMhe/

Answer (score 0):

The red is half the size of the green because the green has an explicit height, whereas the red is inferring its height from its content (a single line of text).  Increase the height of the red explicitly:

```
#menu ul li #menu1 {border:solid 2px red; height:41px;}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought i had understood what "inheritance" means but apparently i dont!

Comment: I thought that by assigning height to the parent: #menu ul li, the ancestors: #menu ul li #menu1....#menu1000000 would get it.

Answer (score 0):

You've set only the size of the green rectangle.

See:
http://dabblet.com/gist/2225892

Block elements start as 0 height. As you add content to them they change height accordingly.

The 1 character is not as big as the parent element, thus it won't be as large.

In this case you need to set the height to 100% and also the box-sizing since you want the border to be within the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can either make the size the same by:

- Removing the size properties from the encapsulating `li` element
- Make the `div` take 100% height of its parent. Setting height in % only works if a element has a fixed width

If you remove the size properties from the `li` it will become very small (as small as its contents). To make it larger you could set the `width:103px;height:43px;` on the `div` instead of on the `li`. The `li` will wrap around the DIV. for example:

`#menu ul li #menu1 {border:solid 2px red;width: 100px;height: 40px}`

or if you want the text in the middle of the box:

`#menu ul li #menu1 {border:solid 2px red;width: 100px;line-height: 40px}`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have 1000 menu items (joking :-)...) wouldn't it be easier to assign height once to the whole #menu ul li ? Why must i assign the same size 1000 times ?!

Comment: You can just assign the size to `#menu li > div` (a `div` directly under a `li` element somewhere inside the element with id `menu`) Or add a class to the div like `<div class="block">` and then make css for it with `.block`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I see better now my misunderstanding  (not mentioning "ignorence") !